# Change color of font-awesome icons with React

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome, react-font-awesome

How do I change color of Font Awesome's icon using React, Firebase, NPM. *Directly*
Current code:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCaretDown} size="2x" />
```

Comment: How are you using the font? Some NPM package? Directly?...

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?  How do you style your elements and have you applied that styling to these elements?  Are you just using plain CSS?  Something else?  Please elaborate on what you've tried and what isn't working.

Comment: You should check this out and include some examples of things you have tried, what  specifically didn't work, etc: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I tried using style directly. My code: `<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCaretDown} size="2x" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use color props in Fontawesome  component. like below

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon = "faCaretDown"   color="green"/ >
```

or else you can use the below,
usually fontawsome inherit colour and css size

```
<span style="font-size: 48px; color: Dodgerblue;">
    <i class="fas fa-bomb"></i>
</span>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).